# Scala <collection>.reduce strange behaviour on generic types

Tags: scala, sum, reduce

I've been wondering, why this piece of code won't compile?

Is there a way in Scala to create method/func that is generic parametrised and allows for such operation like 'reduce'.

Is this behaviour having anything in common with type erasure or is it something else? I would love to see broad explanation of this :)

```
def func2[B <: Int](data: Seq[B]): Unit = {
    val operation = (a: B, b: B) => a.-(b)

    data.reduce(operation)
  }
```

Compiler says:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (B, B) => Int
 required: (Int, Int) => Int
```

Also, in same spirit - is it possible overall to call any 'stream-like' method, on parametrized collection with this method:

```
   def func2[B <: Int](data: Seq[B]): Unit = {
       val operation = (a: B, b: B) => a.-(b)

       data.sum
  }
```

also gives:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[B]
```

Comment: class `Int` is final, you can create a subclass of `Int`

Answer (score 2):

The result of `a.-(b)` is always `Int` and your `operation` function is `(B, B) => Int`. But `reduce` expects a `(B, B) => B` function.

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

So an `(Int, Int) => Int` function is the only one option for the compiler because of `Int` result type of `operation`.

This variant compiles:

```
def func2[B <: Int](data: Seq[B]): Unit = {
    val operation = (a: Int, b: Int) => a.-(b)
    data.reduce(operation)
}
```

`Numeric` isn't covariant. Its interface is `Numeric[T]`. Hense `Numeric[B]` isn't subclass of `Numeric[Int]` for `B <: Int` and there is no implicit `Numeric[B]`.

Comment: Yeah, I've also figured that combination works:
"val operation = (a: Int, b: Int) => a.-(b)", but I was just wondering, is it possible without need to explicitly define "rigid" types of arguments, and just use "B" all over the method body...

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `-` function.

Comment: Look at `Int.-` definitions https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Int.html#-(x:Double):Double. There are no definitions with generic parameters.

Comment: Also, in Scala functions are contravariant by parameter types and covariant by result type. So `(B, B) => Int` isn't subtype of `(B, B) => B` (because `Int` isn't subtype of `B`) and you can't pass `(B, B) => Int` function as `(B, B) => B` parameter.

Comment: Aleksey Bingo! It all boils down to signature of `-`. Also, @dreamsComeTrue what you expect is only possible if the definition of `-` in `Int` were something like `def -(x: A): A` where `[A <: Int]`. But think about it : hypothetically, an implementer of this can subtract `x` from an `Int` value (because `x` is also an `Int`), but how would it convert the `Int` result back to `A`?

Comment: Theoretically (because `Int` is final and you can't inherit it), you can create something like `RichInt` (`RichInt <: Int`) with provided generic `def -(x: B): B` and rewrite your function like `def func2[B<: RichInt](data: Seq[B]): Unit`

Answer (score 2):

> Why I can't put upper types bounds on type of collection, and assume, that type B (with that constraint) just has these methods I need?

Your assumption is correct. Your upper bound on `B` makes the following compile

```
val operation = (a: B, b: B) => a.-(b)
```

And also makes `reduce` available on a `Seq[B]`, because `Seq` is covariant.

Since compiler knows that "`B` ISA `Int`", the `-` method exists on it. However, it's still going to return an `Int`. Because the signature of `+` restricts the return type to `Int`

```
def +(x: Int): Int
```

The `reduce` operation can understand only one type. So if you have

```
reduce[B](operation)
```

It will expect `operation` to be of type `(B,B) => B`

And if you have

```
reduce[Int](operation)
```

It will expect `operation` to be of type `(Int,Int) => Int`

One of the things you *can* do is

```
val operation = (a: Int, b: Int) => a - b
```

This is safe because your `B` is always also an `Int`

Comment: `This is safe because your B is always also an Int` - yeah, but wouldn't it be nice to just put `B` there and not explicitly declare type - a method body with only generic placeholders :) scalac should know that, it is of typeish 'Int' - from method declaration, so it should be smart enough to also resolve these types in operation.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
def func2[B](data: Seq[B], f: (B, B) => B): Unit = {
  val operation = (a: B, b: B) => f(a, b)
  data.reduce(operation)
}
```

Comment: Right, you're correct. But is there somewhere explanation of this behavior? Why I can't put upper types bounds on type of collection, and assume, that type B (with that constraint) just has these methods I need?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

First of all restriction `B <: Int` makes no sense as `Int` is a `final` class in Scala.

Secondly, using `reduce` together with `-` also makes no sense because `-` is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). This is important because `reduce` unlike `reduceLeft`/`reduceRight` or `foldLeft`/`foldRight` does not guarantee the order of the evaluation. Actually

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = reduceLeft(op)
```

is as valid default implementation as

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = reduceRight(op)
```

but obviously they will produce different results for `-` operation.

From a higher level point of view it looks like something similar to what you want to achieve can be done using [type classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) and particularly [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/math/Numeric.html). For example you could have a method like this:

```
def product[B: Numeric](data: Seq[B]): B = {
  val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[B]]
  data.reduce(numeric.times)
}
```

Note that multiplication is commutative so it is a reasonable implementation. Actually this is almost how `sum` and `product` are implemented in the standard library. The main difference is that the real implementation uses `foldLeft` which allows defining the default value for an empty `Seq` (0 and 1 respectively)